Systemverilog/Verilog VCP2000 “Syntax error. Unexpected token: class[_IDENTIFIER].”
I could not figure out what is wrong with the code here :
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/SpPU
Code snippet
1 // Code your testbench here
2 // or browse Examples
3
4 class myclass;
5 endclass

Error message
[2024-09-02 08:46:01 UTC] vlib work && vlog '-timescale' '1ns/1ns' '-v95' +incdir+$RIVIERA_HOME/vlib/uvm-1.1d/src -l uvm -err VCP2947 W9 -err VCP2974 W9 -err VCP3003 W9 -err VCP5417 W9 -err VCP6120 W9 -err VCP7862 W9 -err VCP2129 W9 design.sv testbench.sv  && vsim -c -do "vsim +access+r; run -all; exit"  
VSIMSA: Configuration file changed: `/home/runner/library.cfg'
ALIB: Library "work" attached.
work = /home/runner/work/work.lib
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: class[_IDENTIFIER]." "testbench.sv" 4  6
WARNING VCP2515 "Undefined module: gen_pkt was used. Port connection rules will not be checked at such instantiations." "testbench.sv" 36  15
FAILURE "Compile failure 1 Errors 1 Warnings  Analysis time: 0[s]."
Exit code expected: 0, received: 255
Done

The settings of the simulator are indicated at the 1st line of the error message. I’ve googled this topic but most of the issues were just due to lack of ;

Please include the code and relevant error in your question instead of linking to it.

I believe that’s the purpose of EDA Playground. Or maybe you don’t know how to use it ?

Please see the Help Center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. “If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so—but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.”

I believe the -v95 flag forces the simulator to compile code as Verilog IEEE1364-1995, which doesn't support class. Remove the flag so it can compile as SystemVerilog

Thank you very much @Greg ! Somehow I was just switching that flag among {-v95}, {-v2k}, and {-v2k5} and still get the same error. After removing it, the error was gone and I can proceed with debugging the other syntax errors. Thank you very much for your help !

@renvill, I believe that nneonneo did show compassion and patience. They provided two comments to help you improve your question. Be careful with assumptions: we have no way of knowing who downvoted your question. "I don’t know the full rules yet of this platform"—yet you should already have read the [ask] page that their second comment mentioned.

@Greg the question is reopened; feel free to submit your comment as an answer. Since this error didn’t show up in a quick Google search, I think a definitive answer would be useful to have.

The -v95 flag forces the simulator to compile code as Verilog IEEE1364-1995 which doesn't support class. By removing the flag, the simulator can compile the code as SystemVerilog. SystemVerilog supports class, typedef, enum, int, and other keywords used in your code from the edaplaygroud link.
